# Which rings are rings of continuous functions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis, logic, ring-theory

*Now at [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/423525/can-exists-mathcalxr-cong-c-mathcalx-be-expressed-in-large-infini).*

This is a question for which I've found a number of "near-miss" results online, which may actually be answers but whose direct relevance I haven't been able to see.

Say that a ring $A$ is **spatial** iff there is some topological space $\mathcal{X}$ such that $A\cong C(\mathcal{X})$, where $C(\mathcal{X})$ is the ring of continuous functions $\mathcal{X}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

> Is there a purely algebraic characterization of spatiality?

I've been told that [Gelfand representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand_representation) are relevant here, but I don't immediately see how they answer the question; maybe I'm missing something, though. (Note however that I do mean to ask about rings, rather than more intricate structures like Banach algebras. Also note that I'm not assuming any tameness properties on the spaces which are candidates for witnessing spatiality.)

---

EDIT: "purely algebraic characterization" is of course some serious weasel-wordery. Here's one way to make that precise (and so make possible a rigorous negative answer):

> Is there an $\mathcal{L}^2_{\infty,\infty}$-sentence characterizing the spatial rings?

Here $\mathcal{L}^2_{\infty,\infty}$ is the fully-infinitary version of second-order logic: we allow arbitrary-cardinality Boolean combinations and quantifications (over both first- and second-order objects). Of course, any specific $\mathcal{L}^2_{\infty,\infty}$-sentence can only "reach up" to a particular cardinal, so this isn't actually as overkill as it may appear.

Comment: Since you've had many near misses you might have already seen this, but I think it is the closest one can get to $C(X)$ from a purely algebraic perspective: 
K. Keimel, “Algebres commutatives engendrees par leurs elements idempotents”, Canad. J. Math.,
22 (1970), 1071–1078.

Comment: @Ruy That definitely looks relevant, but since I can't read French (*and* am unfamiliar with sheaf theory) I'm finding this a bit hard-going; can you say what the main result(s) is?

Comment: It classifies commutative $R$-algebras ($R$ is some commutative ring with 1) which are generated by their idempotent elements.  The best results are when $R$ is a field, in which case there is a totally disconnected, locally compact space $X$, such that the given algebra is isomorphic to the locally constant functions with compact support.

Comment: @Ruy Ah, that is interesting. But for most spaces $\mathcal{X}$, won't $C(\mathcal{X})$ *not* be generated (either as a ring or an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra) by its idempotents?

Comment: As I said this is another near miss.  Indeed, if $X$ is connected, then there are no nontrivial idempotents in $C(X)$.

Comment: Here is another near miss which may or may not be of interest: a commutative ring $A$ is isomorphic to a **subring** of $C(X)$ if the set of ring homomorphisms from $A$ to $\mathbb R$ separates points of $A$.  The proof is essentially the same as for Gelfand duality.

Comment: @Ruy Isn't that trivial? Let $H$ be the space of ring homomorphisms from $A$ to $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the discrete topology. Then unless I'm missing something the map $$f: A\rightarrow C(H): a\mapsto (h\mapsto h(a))$$ is a ring embedding if homomorphisms from $A$ to $\mathbb{R}$ separate points in $A$. Are you assuming some tameness about $X$?

Comment: I initially thought about the product topology on $H$ inherited from $\mathbb R^A$ but I guess you are right that the discrete topology also works.  The advantage of the former might be that it has better chances to lead to an isomorphism from $A$ onto $C(X)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136299/discussion-between-ruy-and-noah-schweber).

Comment: IN this paper http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm149/fm14914.pdf, it is shown that $C(X)$ has strong algebraic properties. For example, any prime ideal is contained in a UNIQUE maximal ideal, and every finitely generated ideal is contained in a principal ideal.

Comment: Also, Theorems 4.6 and 4.19 of this paper http://libres.uncg.edu/ir/asu/f/Huffstetler_Keith_1971_Thesis_Study%20Rings%20Continuous%20Functions.pdf show that you may assume that  $X$ is compact Hausdorff.

Comment: @GreginGre, I think theorem 4.19 refers to the algebra of **bounded** continuous functions.

Comment: Gelfand duality gives an algebraic characterization of the rings that are rings of *bounded* continuous functions on some topological space.  Namely, given a ring of bounded continuous functions, it has a canonical $\mathbb{R}$-algebra structure that can be described algebraically (first it is a $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra and then you can extend to $\mathbb{R}$ by using the ordering given by the squares).  Then, you can complexify to get a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra and require that the result is a commutative C*-algebra with respect to the spectral norm.

Comment: (So, the extra structure you were worried about like the Banach algebra structure is not really important--it is actually all uniquely determined by the ring structure.  But all of this only works for *bounded* continuous functions, not all continuous functions.)

Comment: Just as $C_b(X)$ can be canonically identified with $C_b(\beta X)$ and this gives a duality between rings of bounded continuous functions and compact Hausdorff spaces, $C(X)$ can be canonically identified with $C(\nu X)$ where $\nu X$ is the Hewitt realcompactification of $X$, and this gives a duality between rings of continuous functions and realcompact spaces.  So, if a ring $A$ is spatial, there is a canonical choice of $X$ such that it is isomorphic to $C(X)$ (namely the unique such $X$ that is realcompact).

Comment: You can even construct this $X$ from the ring structure of $A$.  (To sketch the construction, take the subring $A_0$ of $A$ consisting of the bounded functions, and take the space $Y$ of maximal ideals in $A_0$.  This $Y$ will be the Stone-Cech compactification of $X$, each element of $A$ can be turned into a function $Y\to [-\infty,\infty]$ and then $X$ can be recovered as the subset of $Y$ on which every element of $A$ takes a finite value.)  What I haven't figured out a way to do is express that $A$ is actually isomorphic to $C(X)$ for this $X$ "algebraically".

Comment: (In particular, there is a canonical way to map $A$ to the ring of real-valued functions on $X$.  You can express that this map is injective, and that every element of its image is continuous.  I don't know how to express that the image contains *all* the continuous functions on $X$, though.  A priori, this would be third-order over $A$: each element of $X$ is a second-order object over $A$, and so functions on $X$ are third-order objects over $A$ and so we're not allowed to quantify over them.)

Comment: Peter Johnstone's *Stone spaces* gives [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/illinois-journal-of-mathematics/volume-3/issue-1/Characterizations-of-the-algebra-of-all-real-valued-continuous-functions/10.1215/ijm/1255455003.full) as a reference for characterizing rings of the form $C(X)$.  This paper does have some characterizations (Theorems 5.6 and Theorem 5.8) but they are not "algebraic" in your sense--they involve quantifying over all possible extensions of the ring of a certain type.

Comment: (In particular, what they do is basically resolve my problem of how to express that the map $A\to C(X)$ is surjective by observing that $C(X)$ will be maximal among all nice extensions of $A$ which do not change the associated space $X$, and so you can say $A\to C(X)$ is surjective by saying $A$ has no nontrivial extensions of this type.)

Comment: @EricWofsey Although your comments don't answer the question, they're very helpful - if you combine them into an answer, I'll award it the bounty.

Answer (score 12):

I do not know the answer to your precise formulation but here are some things you can say about characterizing spatial rings.

First, rings of *bounded* continuous functions can be characterized algebraically using Gelfand duality.  Namely, a commutative ring $A$ is isomorphic to the ring $C_b(X)$ of bounded continuous functions $X\to\mathbb{R}$ for some topological space $X$ iff $A$ satisfies the following properties.  First, $A$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra, and is partially ordered by the relation $x\leq y$ iff $y-x$ is a square.  Moreover, for each $r\in\mathbb{R}$, there is a unique element of $A$ which defines the same Dedekind cut in $\mathbb{Q}$ with respect to this ordering as $r$, and this makes $A$ an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra.  Finally, if you form the complexification $\mathbb{C}\otimes_\mathbb{R} A$, the spectral radius defines a norm on $\mathbb{C}\otimes_\mathbb{R} A$ which makes it a $C^*$-algebra.  (Alternatively, you can directly characterize real bounded continuous functions without going through the complexification.  For instance, for $x\in A$ you can define $\|x\|$ to be the least $r\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ such that $-r\leq x\leq r$ and then it suffices to assume that this is a complete norm on $A$.  See IV.4.4-10 in Peter Johnstone's *Stone spaces*.)

Now, there is an analogue of Gelfand duality for rings of unbounded functions.  Recall that Gelfand duality says that for any topological space $X$, $C_b(X)$ is isomorphic to $C_b(Y)$ for a compact Hausdorff space $Y$ which is unique up to unique compatible homeomorphism (namely, the Stone-Cech compactification $\beta X$ of $X$), and that this gives a contravariant equivalence of categories between the category of rings of the form $C_b(X)$ and the category of compact Hausdorff spaces.  Similarly, for any topological space $X$, $C(X)$ is isomorphic $C(Y)$ for a unique *realcompact* space $Y$ which is unique up to unique compatible homeomorphism and this gives a contravariant equivalence of categories between the category of rings of the form $C(X)$ and the category of realcompact spaces.  This space $Y$ is called the Hewitt realcompactification $\nu X$ of $X$, and can be described as the subset of $\beta X$ to which all elements of $C(X)$ extend continuously.

Now, given a spatial ring $A\cong C(X)$, you can recover $\nu X$ and the canonical map $A\to C(\nu X)$ algebraically as follows.  First, as above, $A$ is partially ordered using squares and this gives $A$ an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra structure.  You can then define the subring $A_0$ of elements of $A$ that are bounded above and below by elements of $\mathbb{R}$ (this will be $C_b(X)$).  This subring is a ring of bounded continuous functions, as characterized above.  Now let $Y$ be the set of maximal ideals of $C_b(X)$ (this will be $\beta X$).  For every $m\in Y$, the quotient $A_0/m$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, and in this way we can map $A_0$ to the set of functions $Y\to\mathbb{R}$.  Give $Y$ the coarsest topology that makes every element of $A_0$ continuous.

Now, we can also evaluate elements of $A$ at points of $Y$ as follows.  Given $x\in A$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $x_n=(x\wedge n)\vee -n$ with respect to our ordering on $A$.  Then $x_n\in A_0$, and we can consider $x_n$ as a function $Y\to\mathbb{R}$.  This sequence of functions $(x_n)$ then converges pointwise to a function $Y\to [-\infty,\infty]$ (this is the unique extension of $x:X\to\mathbb{R}$ to a function $\beta X\to[-\infty,\infty]$).  Let $Z\subseteq Y$ be the set of points at which every element of $A$ takes a finite value (this is $\nu X$).  We then can map $A$ to the set of functions $Z\to\mathbb{R}$.  This gives a characterization of spatial rings: a ring $A$ is spatial iff it satisfies all the above properties and this last map is a bijection from $A$ to $C(Z)$.

Unfortunately, this characterization does not appear to be "algebraic" in your sense.  Almost everything can be done in $\mathcal{L}^2_{\infty,\infty}$, but there is a problem with the very last step.  To say that our map $A\to C(Z)$ is surjective, we need to quantify over functions $Z\to\mathbb{R}$.  Elements of $Z$ are second-order over $A$ (they are maximal ideals in $A_0$), and so functions $Z\to\mathbb{R}$ are third-order over $A$.  (There are various ways you could try to get around this, but I haven't found one that works.  For instance, if you could algebraically state that $Y$ is the Stone-Cech compactification of $Z$, then instead of quantifying over arbitrary functions $Z\to\mathbb{R}$, you can just quantify over functions $Z\to\mathbb{R}$ that are a pointwise limit of a sequence of elements of $A_0$, since you know that every continuous function $Z\to\mathbb{R}$ extends to a continuous function $Y\to[-\infty,\infty]$ which is then the pointwise limit of a sequence of bounded continuous functions $Y\to\mathbb{R}$.  Alternatively, imitating the approach for bounded continuous functions above, you might try to find some more basic algebraic characterization of when a subalgebra of $C(Z)$ is all of $C(Z)$, analogous to the Stone-Weierstrass theorem which is a crucial tool in the proof of Gelfand duality.  I don't know of any such characterization, though.)

Let me finally mention the paper

> *Anderson, Frank W.; Blair, Robert L.*, [Characterizations of the algebra of all real-valued continuous functions on a completely regular space](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/illinois-journal-of-mathematics/volume-3/issue-1/Characterizations-of-the-algebra-of-all-real-valued-continuous-functions/10.1215/ijm/1255455003.full), Ill. J. Math. 3, 121-133 (1959). [ZBL0083.17403](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0083.17403).

which is the only reference I have been able to find on the topic of characterizing spatial rings.  They give two characterizations (Theorem 5.6 and 5.8), but again, these are not "algebraic".  I have not read through all the details of the paper but their approach seems to be basically the same idea as mine.  They characterize the map $A\to C(Z)$ being surjective by characterizing when an extension of $A$ would consist of just adding more continuous functions on $Z$ to the ring, and require that $A$ has no nontrivial extensions of this type.

Comment: Thanks! I've followed this up on MO.

Comment: Does Pro({ closed subsets of affine $\mathbb R$-spaces of finite dim }) form a full subcategory of realcompact spaces?

Comment: @Yai0Phah: I don't think so?  Any inverse limit of closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$s is realcompact, but I don't see any reason to believe that morphisms between such inverse limits are the same as morphisms of formal pro-objects.

Comment: Thanks. Is the category of realcompact spaces monadic over sets?

Comment: @Yai0Phah: No.  Discrete spaces smaller than the first measurable cardinal are realcompact.  So free realcompact spaces are not interesting (until you get to really huge sets): the free realcompact space on a set smaller than the first measurable cardinal is just the discrete space on that set.